# Change the cventry style of moderncv banking to classic one

Tags: moderncv

I started learning LateX recently and i tried to do my own CV.
I used the moderncv theme in banking style. But i would like to have the cventry of the classic style.
I tried to do it with the \renewcommand as suggest by other people for other questions but I didnt managed to get what i want.
I would like to get:
year-year  First information
           Second information
           Third information
Also i would like to be able to leave the third information for example empty. Actually i get an error when i try to.Do i have to delete the {} or leave them with nothing write or something else?

Sorry for the bad english, I don't speak it really well.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}   
\moderncvstyle{banking}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}

\name{One}{Guy}                             
\address{adrres, post code}{}{}
\phone[mobile]{number}                   
\email{mail@mail.mail}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\centering\small{Here comes the title centered and in small}

\raggedright
\section{Formation}

\vspace{5pt}

\subsection{Etudes}

\vspace{3pt}
%With CV entry
%Year-year  Name of university and city
%%%%%%%%%%%%Grade...
%%%%%%%%%%%%Description
\textbf{2012-2014} University and city
\\Degre and grades
\\Description

\subsection{Projet notables}

\subsection{Langues étrangères}
first langage
\\second langage
\\third langage


\subsection{Compétences}
Here comes the skills

\section{Expérience professionnel}





%Here comes experiences with the same structure than the studies
%year-year  first information (Name of the industry and city )
%%%%%%%%%%%%Second information
%%%%%%%%%%%%Third information



\section{Centre d'intérêts}

\begin{itemize}
\item Sport : 
\item Musique : 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to use a command with mandatory arguments which are passed inside braces, you have to use it always, but you can leave empty. For example, `\frac{}{b}` is allowed but not `\frac{b}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks Sigur for your answer.
I will try to put my CV, but I have to remove my personnal information...
To Christian Hupfer, I Will do it as soon as possible but for now it's getting late for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a style that matches this:

```
year-year  First information
           Second information
           Third information
```

then you're probably interested in a change in `\cvitem`. Below I've made a `\newentry`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}   
\moderncvstyle{banking}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{One}{Guy}                             
\address{adrres, post code}{}{}
\phone[mobile]{number}                   
\email{mail@mail.mail}

\newcommand*{\newentry}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{0.125\textwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\dimexpr0.875\textwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth}@{}}
     #3
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

{\centering\small Here comes the title centered and in small\par}

\raggedright

\section{Formation}

\vspace{5pt}

\subsection{Etudes}

\vspace{3pt}

\newentry{2012-2014}{%
    University and city \\
    Degre and grades \\
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque volutpat, 
    neque nec aliquam eleifend, dolor risus sodales leo, ut porta odio nisi in ex.}

\subsection{Projet notables}

\subsection{Langues étrangères}
first language \\
second language \\
third language

\subsection{Compétences}
Here comes the skills

\section{Expérience professionnel}

\newentry{year-year}{%
    First information (Name of the industry and city ) \\
    Second information \\
    Third information}

\section{Centre d'intérêts}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Sport :
  \item Musique :
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by insering

```
 \renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

just befor your cventries

Comment: Oh Sorry i miss explained what i want
Didn't notice that the message didn't had the spaces...
I would like to have the cvitem of this:https://www.overleaf.com/articles/curriculum-vitae/zvckbvcsfrxq#.VPEaZvmG-So
On the banking version.
Your answer exchange the place of information but don't do the alignment which is my problem.
Thanks for your answer

Comment: @user73217 what do you want to change? cvitem or cventry?